# Can't install the ggplot2 package

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to install the ggplot2 package I am getting the following errors & warnings.

```
Warning: failed to download mirrors file (cannot open URL 'https://cran.r-project.org/CRAN_mirrors.csv'); using local file 'C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-42~1.1/doc/CRAN_mirrors.csv'
Error in contrib.url(repos, type) : 
  trying to use CRAN without setting a mirror
In addition: Warning message:
In download.file(url, destfile = f, quiet = TRUE) :
  URL 'https://cran.r-project.org/CRAN_mirrors.csv': status was 'Couldn't connect to server'
> utils:::menuInstallPkgs()
--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
Warning: failed to download mirrors file (cannot open URL 'https://cran.r-project.org/CRAN_mirrors.csv'); using local file 'C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-42~1.1/doc/CRAN_mirrors.csv'
Warning: unable to access index for repository https://repo.miserver.it.umich.edu/cran/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'https://repo.miserver.it.umich.edu/cran/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Error in install.packages(lib = .libPaths()[1L], dependencies = NA, type = type) : 
  argument "pkgs" is missing, with no default
In addition: Warning message:
In download.file(url, destfile = f, quiet = TRUE) :
  URL 'https://cran.r-project.org/CRAN_mirrors.csv': status was 'SSL connect error'
> utils:::menuInstallPkgs()
Warning: unable to access index for repository https://repo.miserver.it.umich.edu/cran/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'https://repo.miserver.it.umich.edu/cran/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Error in install.packages(lib = .libPaths()[1L], dependencies = NA, type = type) : 
  argument "pkgs" is missing, with no default
> utils:::menuInstallPkgs()
Warning: unable to access index for repository https://repo.miserver.it.umich.edu/cran/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'https://repo.miserver.it.umich.edu/cran/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Error in install.packages(lib = .libPaths()[1L], dependencies = NA, type = type) : 
  argument "pkgs" is missing, with no default
> utils:::menuInstallPkgs()
Warning: unable to access index for repository https://repo.miserver.it.umich.edu/cran/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'https://repo.miserver.it.umich.edu/cran/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Error in install.packages(lib = .libPaths()[1L], dependencies = NA, type = type) : 
  argument "pkgs" is missing, with no default
> utils:::menuInstallLocal()
> utils:::menuInstallLocal()
Error in utils:::menuInstallLocal() : 
  Only '*.zip' and '*.tar.gz' files can be installed.
> utils:::menuInstallLocal()
ERROR: dependencies 'digest', 'glue', 'gtable', 'isoband', 'rlang', 'scales', 'tibble', 'withr' are not available for package 'ggplot2'
* removing 'C:/Users/S/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2/ggplot2'
Warning message:
In install.packages(files[tarballs], .libPaths()[1L], repos = NULL,  :
  installation of package ‘C:/Users/S/Documents/ggplot2_3.3.6.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
> utils:::menuInstallPkgs()
Warning: unable to access index for repository https://repo.miserver.it.umich.edu/cran/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'https://repo.miserver.it.umich.edu/cran/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Error in install.packages(lib = .libPaths()[1L], dependencies = NA, type = type) : 
  argument "pkgs" is missing, with no default
```

Comment: server issues perhaps but I would recommend you for fresh install some dependencies are broken looks like

Comment: There's nothing in your question that involves Git. The servers you're using store tarballs (`*.tar.gz`) and zip files (`*.zip`) that whatever package-installer you're using is expecting to find, download, and expand/install.